# grails delete not working

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have the folowing classes

```
class Product {

}

class ProductTest extends Product {

    static hasMany = [events:Event]

}

class Event {

    static belongsTo = [product:ProductTest ]
}
```

When I call

```
def product = Product.get(1)
product.delete(flush:true)
```

I get the error:

```
2015-08-28 16:15:13,770 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException occurred when processing request: [GET] /xx/produkt/deleteProduct/300-fewfwef
Column 'event_id' cannot be null. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Column 'event_id' cannot be null
```

which makes no sense because when I call

```
log.debug product.events
```

it returns an empty list ([]) because I never have associated an event with that product

I tried

```
Product.executeUpdate("DELETE $Product.name WHERE id = :id", [id:product.id])
```

And that strangely works...

I am using the database migration plugin... Maybe that is causing the problem as it might have created the tables wrongly? It is definitely cause by GORM as executeUpdate works but not the GORM equivalent delete(flush:true)

Comment: _"Maybe that is causing the problem as it might have created the tables wrongly?"_ Did you check this?

Comment: I could not find something unusual... I would also suggest that the guys who are working on the plugin did test their stuff...